# UILabel frame width not correct value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nslog

So UILabel isn't giving me the correct value for its frame size for some reason.

First I do the following to create a UILabel

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 10)];
```

And then I try to access and print its width, which should be 15:

```
int width = (int)myLabel.frame.size.width;
NSLog(@"LABEL FRAME WIDTH: %d", width);
```

However, the value that gets printed out is 256. I have no idea why it is behaving like this.

Comment: i dont undastend what need it convert to int value you simply check with `NSLog(@"LABEL FRAME WIDTH: %f", myLabel.frame.size.width);`

Comment: for me its prints the width as 15 only. may i know where you print the width? Is it in same method or?

Comment: may be some where else you are changing the width otherwise it'l give same value.

Comment: If its in same method then u should get 15. If its in different method then make sure myLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Auto Layout. Check once without Auto layout option may be you will get correct value.